# Deprecated conversion from string constant to LPWSTR when filling lpstrFile in OPENFILENAMEW struct

Tags: c++, winapi

It compiles to working code in this example, but if I put more complicated things around it the program shuts down and fails to open the dialog window. The error message is exactly:

> test.cpp:10:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' [-Wwrite-strings]

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
  OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
  ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
  ofn.lpstrFile = L"file name";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a buffer for windows to fill in.

> The file name used to initialize the File Name edit control. The first character of this buffer must be NULL if initialization is not necessary. When the GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file.

Basically, windows fills in the buffer with the path and filename of the selected file after they select a file in the open/save dialog. So basically, your code should look like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t fileBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFile = fileBuffer;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `lpstrFile` member is defined as non-`const` (of type `LPTSTR`) but a string literal is `const`. The description for `lpstrFile` states that it will be populated, written to, when used with particular WINAPI functions. Writing to a string literal is undefined behaviour.

From [`OPENFILENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> The file name used to initialize the File Name edit control. The first character of this buffer must be NULL if initialization is not necessary. **When the GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file.**

To correct point the `lpStrFile` to an array of `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t file[100] = L"file name";

ofn.plstrFile = file;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding the `lpstrFile` field:

> When the GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file.

This is supposed to be a pointer to a buffer that can be written to, and it must be large enough to hold the filename that you select. Pointing it to a constant string is a mistake and will lead to undefined behavior as you have observed.

Answer (score 1):

Non-const pointers to string literals are deprecated, because writing to a string literal causes undefined behavior:

```
const char* s = "abc"; // correct
char* s = "abc"; // deprecated
```

The same applies to `wchar_t` strings.

The `ofn.lpstrFile` pointer is non-const and is meant to point to a writable buffer.  You need to provide a writable buffer and set the `ofn.plstrFile` pointer to that buffer.

```
wchar_t buf[1024];
ofn.plstrFile = buf;
```

See the [OPENFILENAME documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.